# Putting multiple rows behind each other with same column [python, pandas, dataframes]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe and want to make it that all rows are behind each other with the corresponding column name. Ideally I want it to work for an n-amount of rows. Couldn't find a solution though (on SO & Docs). Hope one of you can help me out here :)

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| COL A | COL B  | COL C | COL D | COL E | COL F |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B      | C     | D     | E     | F     |
| G     | H      | I     | J     | K     | L     |
| M     | N      | O     | P     | Q     | R     |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| COL A | COL B  | COL C | COL D | COL E | COL F | COL A | COL B | COL C | COL D | COL E | COL F |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B      | C     | D     | E     | F     | G     | H     | I     | J     | K     | L     |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but I'm using concatenation (`pd.concat`) on all the rows separately:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': ['A', 'E', 'I'], 
    'colB': ['B', 'F', 'J'], 
    'colC': ['C', 'G', 'K'],
    'colD': ['D', 'H', 'L'],
})

pd.concat([df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1], df.iloc[2]], axis='rows').to_frame().T
```